# Only in index page my session wont start not sure because its my host

Tags: php, ajax, session, setcookie

Only in my index page session won't start but if I go to another page the session would start or if I go to another page than back to the index page the session would start. The way I have it set up I'm using jQuery AJAX. If it goes through it should create a session than the page refreshes than the session start but it won't start that's the problem.

Top section of the index page:

```php
ob_start;
error_reporting(0);
session_set_cookie_params(3600 * 24 * 7, '/', '.example.com');
session_start();
```

If I get rid of `error_reporting(0)` I get these errors

> session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already 
>   session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter

I don't get those errors in other pages

Comment: yes on all my  pages theirs `session_start()`;

Comment: My guess is that you have content over top your PHP, either whitespace, HTML, or a space before your `<?php`. You can't have anything on top of `<?php` such as `<div>...`, or `<table>...` etc. Check to see if you do. That is why you're getting the error message of "`headers already sent`". Show your full code.

Comment: error_reporting(-1); // it will guide you

Comment: thank you so much it works now. I had that issue for a long time and I never thought white space would effect it. I knew html codes would but not white space. Thank you for your time

Comment: @Juan I will post it as an answer then.

Comment: @Juan I posted it below.

Comment: @Juan You're very much welcome, glad I could help. Cheers (*Peace*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have content over top your PHP, either whitespace, HTML, or a space before your `<?php`. You can't have anything on top of `<?php` such as `<div>`..., or `<table>`... etc.

Check to see if you do. That is why you're getting the error message of "`headers already sent`".

Answer (score 0):

Move the session functions above everything else. Also, `ob_start` is a function and must be invoked.

`error_reporting()` should always be set to `-1` while you are working on the code. When it is uploaded to the server it should be set to `0`. It is usually easier to handle it using the `php.ini` file.

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600 * 24 * 7, '/', '.example.com');
session_start();
error_reporting(-1);
ob_start();
// Do something
// Call whateter ob_* function you need
```

I suggest you always [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). There is *a lot* of help to be had there. Be sure to read the comments as well.